# How to check for duplicate value in URL query string

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

How do I detect duplicate keys in a URL query string:

Example:

```
http://example.com/investments?sector[112-122-111-106-111-123-109-123]
```

Should result in `111` and `123` being marked as duplicates.

Comment: Show some effort in trying to write your own code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best would be to put all values into an array and use this to check:

```
if(count(array_unique($array))<count($array))
{
    // Array has duplicates
}
else
{
    // Array does not have duplicates
}
```

Or

```
function has_dupes($array){
 $dupe_array = array();
 foreach($array as $val){
  if(++$dupe_array[$val] > 1){
   return true;
  }
 }
 return false;
}
```

Or even

```
function showDups($array)
{
  $array_temp = array();

   foreach($array as $val)
   {
     if (!in_array($val, $array_temp))
     {
       $array_temp[] = $val;
     }
     else
     {
       echo 'duplicate = ' . $val . '<br />';
     }
   }
}


$array = array(1,2,2,4,5);
showDups($array);
```

Comment: It's not working...                                         if(count(array_unique($_GET['sector']))<count($_GET['sector']))
                             {
                                 echo 'Array has duplicates';

                             }
                             else
                             {
                                 echo 'Array does not have duplicates';

                             }

Comment: What about it is not working?

Comment: I have updated my answer, there are 2 new methods that you can try, or are you having trouble inserting the value in the URL into an array?

Comment: it's working .... thnx